# puppet file source location not found

Tags: puppet

Hello I am new with Puppet.

I just created a simple file resource, but Agent failed to find the file location from Master.

```
file { '/tmp/file01'
  ensure => file,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '0644',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/file01',
}
```

File is in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/mymodule/files/file01`.

Agent got:

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[east.test.net]/File[/tmp/file01]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/mymodule/file01

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere in your original code?

Comment: "Could not retrieve" is not necessarily "could not find".  In particular, if any manner of access control prevents the puppet / puppetserver user from reading the file or any directory in the path to it then you will receive such errors as you present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put two points "**:**" after the file title, use this way:

```
file { '/tmp/file01':
  ensure => file,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '0644',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/file01',
}
```